# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Tags: linux, shell

I am getting the following 2 error outputs when i try to run manually my script below. What i do not understand is why does it complain that it can not find matching character for `')'` ? where as if i extract whats inside the `then/fi` and put this into a single file and run it it on its own it works just fine as in it sends email as it should.

```
./rsnapshot-log-checker: line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./rsnapshot-log-checker: line 25: syntax error: unexpected end of file

grep "ERROR" /var/log/rsnapshot.log | \
while read line ; do
        echo "$line" | grep "ERROR"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
                to=warning@bla.com
                subject="Error rsnapshot - `hostname`"
                from=`hostname`@bla.com
                daemail=$(cat <<! <-- line 15
                        From: $from
                        To: $to Subject:
                        $subject You might want to check this... !) <-- maching haracter for )

                echo "$daemail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
        fi
done
<-- line 25
```

Comment: I was directed here when searching for a similar error:  /usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file.   

In my case as I had % symbols in the a crontab entry the following resolved the errors: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/using-the-system-date-time-in-a-cron-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Here document redirection operator(<<) on line 15 that is causing issue. 
Use following:

```
daemail=$(cat
         echo "From:" $from
         echo  "To:" $to "Subject:"
         echo  $subject "You might want to check this... !")
```

Comment: Yup that seems to have done the trick. Although it still slightly baffles me why it works on its own and not inside the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

The here document delimiter [has to appear on a line by itself](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: Yup i can see the issue that was here - however Nishu answer provides a nice clean solution so i accepted his answer :) You +1